# unable to start another activity at click of button

Tags: java, android

My project is fairly simple for training purposes only. I am trying to load another interface/view/activity when I click a button on my main layout. Here is the code for the main activity:

package com.example.interfacemanipulation;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "Something Here....";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void goToWelcomeActivityMethod(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.welcomeMessage);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

And this is the code in the other activity:

```
package com.example.interfacemanipulation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.welcome, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

the code here is basically modified from Google documentation. I just want to be able to load the view of the second activity with label in it. Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.interfacemanipulation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.interfacemanipulation.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.interfacemanipulation.WelcomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I've only been trying android for the last 4 days...so I appreciate your support

Comment: I don't see where you call `goToWelcomeActivityMethod`... or is that what you're having trouble with?

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` this layout for MainActivity did you define any layout for WelcomeActivity ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems: 1. You don't have the button to take you to the activity (or at least you haven't shown it in the code you posted. If you do, then you don't have the `onClickListener` set for that button). 2. You don't call the method that takes you to your second activity.

To have a button that takes you to another activity, you need to add the button to the layout, and then add the `onClickListener`, which executes your `goToWelcomeActivityMethod` when you click on it, like so:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "Something Here....";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //this will insert the button into the Main Activity layout
        Button goToWelcome = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goToWelcome);

        //this is the onClickListener which will call the method to go to the next activity
        goToWelcome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View v)
        {
           goToWelcomeActivityMethod();
        }
         });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    //you don't need to pass in the View
    public void goToWelcomeActivityMethod()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.welcomeMessage);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Then in your XML file make sure you add the button too:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/goToWelcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Go To Welcome" />
```

Answer (score 0):

in the main activity's layout XML, add the attribute `android:onClick="goToWelcomeActivityMethod"` to the button declaration.
In this way, the method `goToWelcomeActivityMethod` is called when you press the button.

For the "other" way, check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html